# Rsync: Only preserve meta (time, group, etc) on files and sub-directories, not root directory

Tags: macos, unix, rsync

I am copying some files (all except hidden ones) using rsync from one place to another using this command:

```
rsync -Cav --delete --exclude=.* /Some/Directory/ other-host:/Other/Directory
```

It works nice except that I get the following errors:

> rsync: chgrp "/Other/Directory/." failed: Operation not permitted (1)
>   rsync: failed to set times on "/Other/Directory/.": Permission denied (13)

That is understandable because I do in fact not have those permissions, and I also do not want to change the group of that directory. I only want to do this for all the files and directories that are *in* that directory. Is there any way to solve this? Tried to `--exclude=.` and `--exclude=./`, but those didn't work.

Any ideas? I have no idea how to fix this...

---

**More details**: This is on Mac OS X, and the directories I am syncing is from a local mounted volume to the `/Users/Shared/` directory on the other host. That directory has user *root* and group *wheel*. The files inside it has user *admin* and group *staff* and so does the local source directory.

---

**Temporar solution**: Still curious how I can solve this, but since I don't know how to do that yet, I "solved" this by using a different directory than `/Users/Shared` for those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set permissions with rsync for all files but the root directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1444389/set-permissions-with-rsync-for-all-files-but-the-root-directory)

Answer (score -1):

If you know that `other-host:/Other/Directory` already exists you could try:

```
rsync -Cav --delete --exclude=.* /Some/Directory/* other-host:/Other/Directory/
```

then it shouldn't try to do anything with the root directory other than create files/dirs in it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that it doesn't delete any files in the root directory which get removed from the original directory.