# Set permissions with rsync for all files but the root directory

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync

I want to sync two directories with rsync, preserving the permissions of all files. My user `foo` does have write access to the target directory, but does not own it.

```
$ ls -l                                                                                                                                                                                
total 8
drwxrwx--- 2 foo  foo 4096 Jun  3 16:01 a
drwxrwxr-x 3 root foo 4096 Jun  3 16:02 b
```

While syncing does work, it causes a permission error and a bad exit code:

```
$ rsync -av  -O  --delete a/ b/                                                                                                                                                        
sending incremental file list
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/tmp/r/b/.": Operation not permitted (1)
deleting 2
./
1

sent 115 bytes  received 138 bytes  506.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I am aware, that I could use the `--no-perm` option, but this would prevent setting the permissions of any files and not just of the target directory.

Another solution would be to use `rsync -av --delete a/* b/`, but this would prevent deleted files in `a/` from being removed in `b/`.

This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/127670/rsync-only-preserve-meta-time-group-etc-on-files-and-sub-directories-not-r), which remains unanswered since 2010 :-(

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495795/165358), detailing the judicious use of the ending slash, help in any way?

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Are you sure? See the section "Slash on Source Only" in the article [Rsync – To Slash or Not To Slash?](http://qdosmsq.dunbar-it.co.uk/blog/2013/02/rsync-to-slash-or-not-to-slash/)

Comment: Yes, I am sure. My problem is not with copying the wrong files but with setting the permissions. If it weren't for the permissions, the file copying would do exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: I don't understand: Isn't your problem syncing the *contents* of the folders rather than *folders and content*?

Comment: No. The syncing works just fine. I just get an error message due to lacking permissions.

Comment: Just to be sure: You tried using `a/ b` rather than `a/ b/`?

Comment: Probably the linux forum would be more appropriated for such questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Another solution would be to use `rsync -av --delete a/* b/`, but this would prevent deleted files in `a/` from being removed in `b/`.

And *then* you run

```
rsync -rv --delete --existing --ignore-existing a/ b/
```

to deal with this. You don't use `-a` here so the ownership of the target directory is not a problem.

From `man 1 rsync`:

> `--existing`, `--ignore-non-existing`
>   This tells `rsync` to skip creating files (including directories) that do not exist yet on the destination. If this option is combined with the `--ignore-existing option`, no files will be updated (which can be useful if all you want to do is delete extraneous files).

<sup>(Credits to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/713577).)</sup>

---

Improvements:

- In general `*` is not enough to match all files and directories. You also need `.[!.]*` if you have dot files, and `..?*` if you have file names beginning with two dots. In Bash `dotglob` helps, so additional patterns are not needed:

  ```
  # in Bash
  shopt -s dotglob
  rsync -av --delete a/* b/
  ```

  But you need to make sure that the pattern expands to something. If it doesn't, `rsync` will get its literal form and complain. Creating a dummy (temporary) file in `a/` may be inelegant, but it will certainly make the pattern expand. If you remove the file before you run the second `rsync` then it will be removed from the destination as well.
- If you ever decide to work from within `a/` directory, the pattern will become `*`. In this case you should use [double dash (`--`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) or modify the pattern (`./*`) so file names like `-n` are not treated as options.

An example solution may be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob

tmpf="$(mktemp -p a/)" || exit 202
rsync -av --delete a/* b/
rm "$tmpf"
rsync -rv --delete --existing --ignore-existing a/ b/
```

Notes:

- Each `rsync` generates its own exit status, you need additional logic to tell if everything was OK.
- If there are many objects in `a/` then the first invocation of `rsync` may yield [`argument list too long`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/10765659). Possible solutions:

  - `find` + `xargs`.
  - Processing objects one by one in a loop:

    ```
    for f in a/*; do
       rsync -av --delete -- "$f" b/
    done
    ```

    (in this case use `shopt -s nullglob` beforehand and you won't even need a dummy file).

    Note I used `--` even though it's not necessary in this particular case (because expanded `$f` must start with `a/`). But let's say you modify the code and change `a/*` to `*`. Then you need to add `--` in *another line*, it's very easy to miss this.